# Передача простейшей капчи в base64

Tags: javascript, cookie, captcha

Всем доброго дня. Есть полностью готовый скрипт на javascript, который выполняет определённые действия, после чего вылезает капча:

[image: деловой кот]

Каким образом можно извлечь капчу в виде рисунка для её последующей обработки?

```
`var s = $('img.captchaImage').first().attr('src');
var img = "https://***/" + s + ".png";
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
dataURL = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
encodeURIComponent(dataURL);`
```

Данный код выдаёт ошибку:

`Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, SVGImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap.`

Собственно, подскажите как получить рисунок из страницы (при обращении к адресу капчи сервер генерирует новую). Были сообщения, что необходимо обращаться с теми куками, что сервер прислал с капчей, однако в этом я не силён.

Comment: Обращение через DOM также не помогло, ошибка аналогичная.

Comment: Решение найдено - при обращении к DOM элементу необходимо использовать нативные функции javascript (я примешал jquery).